# Java servlet and persistence structure

Tags: java, jdbc, jackson

I have a java webapp that has a servlet doPost which accepts some json POST. Lets call it a "Person". So it receives something like { name: "Joe", age: 35 }. Then there's also a databind class for jackson that captures this... like

```
public class Person {
  public String name;
  public int age;
}
```

I currently have the DB stuff happening inside the Servlet class. So like the servlet receives the request, deserializes it to a Person object, and then takes that resultant object and creates a JDBC connection and runs an insert. What is the best way to structure this? Is this all right? I feel like the persistence should be more linked to the object itself than to the servlet. Should I put the DB functionality into the Person obj? Or create some new "thing" to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel like the persistence should be more linked to the object itself
>   than to the servlet.

Neither are correct, basically, we need to layer the application properly i.e, we should **not mix up both Front end (user interface) concerns and business logic** and check below for more explanation on layering the web application.

> Should I put the DB functionality into the Person obj? Or create some
>   new "thing" to handle it?

No, you need to handle the data access layer separately like using a DAO (Data Access Object) or Repository layer.

In general, the web application architecture works like this:

**HTML/JSP -> Servlet & Controller classes -> Service Layer -> DAO Layer -> Database**

Each one of these layers is meant for its own reasons and we should not mix the concerns.

Now specifically talking about the DAO layer (look here how [DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) pattern works), there are various frameworks available to make things easier and ORM (Object Relational Mapping) is the concept you might be interested in. Just to name few, the popular ORM frameworks are [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) and [Spring data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

---

**UPDATE:**

> So, the servlet accepts the request, deserializes the data to some
>   data bind classes that match the JSON schema. Then it passes those to
>   some "service layer" that does some kind of manipulation and generates
>   DAO objects that match the table structures and saves it off?

You are almost there, the only thing you are missing is that DAO objects are singleton classes (they don't hold the data, just they provide methods to access the database) and the model/entity beans are really used to save the data.

You can refer the below simple example assuming that it is accessing the `PRODUCT` table in the database:

**ProductDAOImpl class (singleton object):**

```
public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO { //or ProductRepository

    public boolean save(Product product) {
        //add implementation
    }

    public List<Product> queryProducts() {
        //add implementation
    }

    public Product queryUniqueProduct(String productId) {
        //add implementation
    }

    //etc...any other methods you would like
}
```

**Product class (one object for each request from client/user):**

```
public class Product { //It is an Entity class

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private int price;

    //all other fields

    //getters and setters
}
```

---

> What if you have a mismatch between request and data model?

Always, ensure that both presentation layer beans and entity (database) model beans should be separate i.e., it is **not a good practice to share the beans across these two layers** because one handles business logic and other is for user interface (frontend), both should be **loosely coupled**.

Comment: So, the servlet accepts the request, deserializes the data to some databind classes that match the json schema. Then it passes those to some "service layer" that does some kind of manipulation and generates DAO objects that match the table structures and saves it off?

Comment: Added an example, look above

Comment: What if you have a mismatch between request and data model... Like, you receive a POST of a "person" json like, "{name:joe, age:21, address: {street:fake, city:seattle}}  send this to a "person" controller that creates a "Person" POJO and a "PersonDAO" then utilizes an "AddressDAO" to do any data manipulation?

Comment: Updated my answer, you can check it